# Given a list of GPS positions, how do I display route using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, gps, routes

I have lists of between 100 and 10000 GPS location from vehicles driving around during some timespan.

I want to display that on a Google Map, using their API (with the Business licence if that matters).

As I see it, there are 3 options, all with problems:

1) Draw a polyline between all positions. Some positions are not that accurate so it looks like the route hits some buildings next to the road. I know that all positions are on a road. Also, it cuts some corners, and it doesn't look professional.

2) Display just the GPS positions in the map. This is not good either since the GPS positions are off the road (which they shouldn't be).

3) Draw the route using Maps API. This limits us to using 23 waypoints between the start and end positions. The route looks excellent and it follows the road (GPS positions next to the road are moved to the road automatically). But especially for longer time spans, this option means that the route displayed is incorrect (Google guesses the route taken between the waypoints - so from the 10000 GPS positions it only uses 23). And we can't display a clearly incorrect route.

Does anyone have a good/better way to show a driven route on Google Maps that follows the road but takes into account all/many given GPS positions?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not chain the route using the maps API? It's not something I've done before so this answer could be a little vague but would it not be possible to segment your list of coordinates into chunks of 23 fire the requests and then display the resultant routes on the map?

I'm not overly sure on the return format so it may be necessary to mess with the output in order to give the illusion of the route, also you will likely not need to use every coordinate (perhaps exclude those that are within a small distance of each other for example being stuck at lights), otherwise the requests may take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

We've actually moving away from option 3. The reason is that when the positions get moved to the nearest road, that is not always correct (like if you're driving on a parking lot), so since that doesn't always give the correct route, then we'll not take that path.

So I don't know if it's possible to chain several routes in the same map.